# Fastest way to filter a numpy array by a set of values

Tags: python, numpy

I am pretty new to numpy, I also am using pypy 2.2 which has limited numpy support (see http://buildbot.pypy.org/numpy-status/latest.html) but what I'm trying to do is filter an array by a set of values (i.e keep subarray if it contains a value in a set). I can do with a list comprehension but I'd rather do without the intermediate list as on longer arrays it isn't fast and I can't help but think numpy filtering will be faster.

```
>> a = np.array([[   368,    322, 175238,      2],
       [   430,    382, 121486,      2],
       [   451,    412, 153521,      2],
       [   480,    442, 121468,      2],
       [   517,    475, 109543,      2],
       [   543,    503, 121471,      2],
       [   576,    537, 100566,      2],
       [   607,    567, 121473,      2],
       [   640,    597, 153561,      2]])

>> b = {121486, 153521, 121473}

>> np.array([x for x in a if x[2] in b])

>> array([[   430,    382, 121486,      2],
   [   451,    412, 153521,      2],
   [   607,    567, 121473,      2]])
```

Comment: Your solution might be the fastest, depending on sizes of `a` and `b`, since it can take advantage of set's fast `in`, which I don't think numpy can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in one line, but you have to use `list(b)`, so it might not actually be any faster:

```
>>> a[np.in1d(a[:,2], list(b))]
array([[   430,    382, 121486,      2],
       [   451,    412, 153521,      2],
       [   607,    567, 121473,      2]])
```

It works because `np.in1d` tells you which of the first item are in the second:

```
>>> np.in1d(a[:,2], list(b))
array([False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

---

For large `a` and `b`, this is probably faster than your solution, as it still uses `b` as a set, but builds only boolean array instead of rebuilding the entire array one line at a time.  For large `a` and small `b`, I think `np.in1d` might be faster.

```
ainb = np.array([x in b for x in a[:,2]])
a[ainb]
```

For small `a` and large `b`, your own solution is probably fastest.

Comment: Ah yes that's the one. I'll remove my answer. So to be clear the result is given by `a[np.in1d(a[:,2], list(b))]`

Comment: In my timings on pypy this is marginally faster even converting set to list each time! 
In [113]: %timeit a[np.in1d(a[:,2], list(d))]
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 µs per loop

In [99]: %timeit np.array([x for x in a if x[2] in b])
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 µs per loop

Comment: @Handloomweaver The main issue with such a small example is the set -> list -> np.array operation of `b` taking up 50% of the total execution time.

Comment: Would suggest you use boolean indexing. `mask = np.zeros_like(a[:,2], dtype=bool); mask[list(b)] = 1; a[mask]`. in1d isn't very fast.

Comment: @seberg I don't understand how that would work since `b` aren't indices.

Answer (score 0):

For relatively small inputs like those in your question, the fastest method is by far and large the naïve one:

```
np.array([x for x in a if x[2] in b])
```

This would be true especially for PyPy.

For larger inputs, [@askewchan solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333146/5218354) with NumPy may be faster:

```
a[np.in1d(a[:,2], list(b))]
```

However, when using CPython, a Numba-based implementation would be even faster (at all scale):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.jit
def custom_filter(arr, values):
    values = set(values)
    n, m = arr.shape
    result = np.empty((n, m), dtype=arr.dtype)
    k = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if arr[i, 2] in values:
            result[k, :] = arr[i, :]
            k += 1
    return result[:k, :].copy()


@nb.jit
def custom_filter2(arr, values):
    values = set(values)
    n, m = arr.shape
    k = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if arr[i, 2] in values:
            k += 1
    result = np.empty((k, m), dtype=arr.dtype)
    k = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if arr[i, 2] in values:
            result[k, :] = arr[i, :]
            k += 1
    return result
```

A quick glimpse into benchmarks:

```
aa = np.tile(a, (1000, 1))
bb = set(list(range(121000, 122000)))


%timeit np.array([x for x in a if x[2] in b])
# 8.54 µs ± 110 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit custom_filter(a, tuple(b))
# 1.59 µs ± 179 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit custom_filter2(a, tuple(b))
# 1.45 µs ± 21.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit a[np.in1d(a[:,2], tuple(b))]
# 25.2 µs ± 1.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.array([x for x in aa if x[2] in b])
# 6.76 ms ± 313 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit custom_filter(aa, tuple(b))
# 90.6 µs ± 3.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit custom_filter2(aa, tuple(b))
# 135 µs ± 5.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit aa[np.in1d(aa[:, 2], tuple(b))]
# 147 µs ± 9.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.array([x for x in aa if x[2] in bb])
# 7.26 ms ± 176 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit custom_filter(aa, tuple(bb))
# 226 µs ± 5.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit custom_filter2(aa, tuple(bb))
# 278 µs ± 10.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit aa[np.in1d(aa[:, 2], tuple(bb))]
# 756 µs ± 62.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```